# Investigating Circular Motion using a Whirling Bung

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

[image: Whirling Bung Diagram]

This experiment is shown in my book.

The book says 'a mass of weight 1.0N is attached on the nylon thread. This creates a centripetal force F of 1.0N on the bung.'

However, isn't there a component of the rubber bung also contribute to the tension and therefore the centripetal force?

Comment: The tension *is* the centripetal force here.

Comment: @probably_someone so even though the rubber bang has mass and therefore weight, it doesn't contribute to the tension of the thread at all?

Comment: It does contribute! The weight of the rubber bung is precisely what the tension in the thread has to balance.

Comment: @probably_someone oh so the weight of the mass (therefore the tension) balances the weight of the rubber bung? If that's right, please put your comment as an answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it does! The tension in the thread is affected both by the weight of the central mass and by the weight of the rubber bung; as you spin the rubber bung faster, the tension in the rope on the bung end tilts further and further askew from the direction of gravity, meaning the tension must grow larger so that its vertical component balances gravity. This is happily in line with physical intuition.